# Profile image disappeared on backPress Button

Tags: java, android, firebase, imageview

I have an activity that contains an ImageView for showing user photo.
the user select an image from phone gallery and when he is done the image upload to firebase storage and return to the ImageView.

**the problem is:** when the user go to another activity (or on back button pressed) and return to UserProfile activity the image is no longer exist inside the ImageView.

how can i load the image when UserProfile activity start?

this is my UserProfile Activity

```
    public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2 ;
    private ImageButton userImage;
    private Button save_changes;
    private EditText user_name;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private Uri mImageUri ,downloadUri;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        save_changes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savechanges);
        user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name2);
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


        userImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_INTENT);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).
                    setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);
        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mImageUri = result.getUri();
            }
            else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }

        save_changes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = user_name.getText().toString();
                StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("photos").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
                filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        Picasso.with(UserProfile.this).load(downloadUri).into(userImage);
                        Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this,"התמונה עלתה בהצלחה",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but you can do one thing create a static variable of Bitmap type when the image is selected assign that bitmap variable the value of bitmap from gallery. 
And on your onStart of your activity first check if that static bitmap variable is null if not so put the bitmap into your imageView

Answer (score 0):

When you launched another activity from current activity your previous activity gets destroyed. so all the variables and the image which set to the image view also garbage collected.

For that you can save your bitmap inside onSaveInstance()

Overide below method inside your activity

```
 @Override 
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable("BitmapImage", bitmap);
    }
```

Write below code inside onCreate() which we can get the saved bitmap

```
  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      image = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("BitmapImage");
      targetImage.setImageBitmap(image); // set the bitmap.     
    }
```

If you have imagePath we can also save that and get that using same approach.

Hope these help you.

Comment: and if im using Uri to retrive the image from firebase storage? what can i do?

Comment: Then you have request to firebase and then get image from their. But you can even save the bitmap.

Comment: Im not so familiar with bitmap.. can you take a look at my code above and explain what changes do i need to do?

Comment: plz!! can someone help me with that? I have tried evrything so far but no success!